# Redirect ?src=URLHERE

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i would like to be able to redirect my long link to a shorter one,

From this: http://mydomain.com/deploy/inc/PhpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=URLHERE
To this: http://mydomain.com/PhpThumb/URLHERE

This is what i've tried to do in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectRule ^PhpThumb/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$    deploy/inc/PhpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=$1    [NC,L]
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Edit, this is whats in my .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /_1/www/index.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 403 /_1/www/index.php?error=403


RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^PhpThumb$ /deploy/inc/PhpThumb/phpThumb.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^src=.+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+PhpThumb/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ deploy/inc/PhpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=%1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

Comment: `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` will only accept these chars (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -). In a URL normally you have more, like `:`, `/`, `?`. You'll need to change your regex to allow them.

Comment: Show us the link that does not work as expected.

Comment: This is the main link that works:
http://zontm.co.uk/deploy/inc/PhpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/1394213_167354636805856_1074638127_n.png

But this is the shortened one that doesnt:
http://zontm.co.uk/PhpThumb/https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/1394213_167354636805856_1074638127_n.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable for this redirection since you're passing a URL as a part of the original URL.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^src=.+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(phpthumb)/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /(%1)/?src=%2 [QSA,L,NE]
```

Comment: That breaks my ErrorDocument 404 for some odd reason, and still doesnt work.

Comment: Put that in my .htaccess and tried going to this link: 
http://zontm.co.uk/PhpThumb/https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/1394213_167354636805856_1074638127_n.png
Still a 404 not found.

Comment: I had already tested that and found it working. If you have more rules in your .htaccess then post in your question. Also make sure there is no other .htaccess anywhere else?

Comment: Added my htaccess, gonna rename previous ones to .htaccess1 since i dont need them at the mo.

Comment: Not really no. Let me just clear out my old folders on the server first then ill get back to you.

Comment: Looks like Filezilla wont connect to my domain and SmartFTP wont open up. Sorry about this.

Comment: Ok no hurry, take your time.

Comment: K, so the FTP clients wont work, so i used an online one (which will have to do). Deleted all other files apart from the PhpThumbs and the index page and the .htaccess.

Comment: I can kinda get it to work when using 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^PhpThumb$ /deploy/inc/PhpThumb/phpThumb.php

Comment: Problem with `RewriteRule ^PhpThumb$` rule is that `https://fbcdn-sphotos...` will become `https:/fbcdn-sphotos` stripping double slash into one.

Comment: Im trying to see if the rewrite rule picks up the file, it doesnt seem to be.

Comment: Ive got this to work:
[link](http://zontm.co.uk/PhpThumb/?src=https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1003945_167354660139187_1262859237_n.png)

Comment: Yes last URL will definitely work. Any other .htaccess in `PhpThumb`?

Comment: Theres no .htaccess in phpthumb (had to change it to small T for some odd reason)

Comment: Tried going to 
http://zontm.co.uk/phpthumb/https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1003945_167354660139187_1262859237_n.png

with your htaccess code, mine commented out, not found. 
I dont get it.

Comment: But when you goto: `http://zontm.co.uk/phpthumb/?src=https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1003945_167354660139187_1262859237_n.png` does it work?

Comment: Not with your code. For some odd reason your code doesnt link /phpthumb/ to the .php file (according to the web server, since it throws out a 404)

Comment: You wrote above that `http://zontm.co.uk/PhpThumb/?src=https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1003945_167354660139187_1262859237_n.png` link works. Mind it this is **?src=** link not pretty one.

Comment: Give me a minute, going to upload the image to the server.

Comment: It didnt pick up the internal image.

Comment: You mean `http://zontm.co.uk/PhpThumb/?src=https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos‌​-ak-ash3/1003945_167354660139187_1262859237_n.png` also doen't work for you?

Comment: I changed the config file in the phpThumb file, and it works for internal images, not external images dont work, but thats fine.

Ill stick with the way i have it for now, least it works right, i guess. Thanks for your help by the way.